# Face/movement recognition with camera in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I have an app that is located in a showroom. It cycles through several pictures. Now what I been requested to do is to add functionality so that when the camera detects a face, it needs to change to a video.

How can I accomplish this in objective C?  I am using iPad 2, but can move to the new iPad

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CIFaceDetector`, apple sample code [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SquareCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011190)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [OpenCV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/). Demo App is hosted at [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/ios-face-detection/).